# How do I pass a String from the user input in a SwiftUI TextField to a ViewController view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, observableobject

I have a SwiftUI application. For the purposes of this, it is 3 views:

1. NewPost (SwiftUI view that contains a TextField)
2. RecordVideoViewWrapper (which references RecordView, which references the RecordVideoViewController in Storyboard)
3. VideoPlaybackViewController (segue from RecordVideoViewController to this VC)

***I want to take the user input from the TextField in NewPost, and pass it to RecordViewWrapper, and eventually display it as a Label on VideoPlaybackViewController***

My code is below. The error that comes up when I try to move from NewPost to RecordViewWrapper is:

"Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type Post2 found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for Post2 may be missing as an ancestor of this view."

***NewPost***

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct NewPost: View {
    @State var post: String = ""
    @EnvironmentObject var post2: Post2
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                Text("Create New Post")

                TextField("Placeholder", text: $post)

                //continue button
                NavigationLink(destination: RecordViewWrapper().environmentObject(post2), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.post2.name = self.post
                        print(self.post2.name)
                        self.selection = 1
                    }) {
                        Text("Next")
                    }
                }


                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

***Post2 (Model)***

```
import Foundation

class Post2: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = ""
}
```

***RecordVideoViewWrapper***

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import UIKit

struct RecordViewWrapper: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var post2: post2

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                RecordView().environmentObject(post2)

            }

            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

***RecordView***

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Combine

struct RecordView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

        let camPreview = UIView()

        let cameraButton = UIButton()

        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

        var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

        var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

        var outputURL: URL!

        @EnvironmentObject var post2: Post2

        typealias UIViewControllerType = RecordVideoViewController


    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<RecordView>) -> RecordView.UIViewControllerType {
            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let mainViewController: RecordVideoViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RecordVideoViewController") as! RecordVideoViewController
            return mainViewController


        }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: RecordView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<RecordView>) {
            //
            print("updateUIViewController \(uiViewController)")
        }
    }
```

***RecordVideoViewController***

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class RecordVideoViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate, ObservableObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var camPreview: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIButton!

    @EnvironmentObject var post2: Post2

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    var activeInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!

    var outputURL: URL!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if setupSession() {
            setupPreview()
            startSession()
        }

        cameraButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let cameraButtonRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(RecordVideoViewController.startCapture))
        cameraButton.addGestureRecognizer(cameraButtonRecognizer)
        camPreview.addSubview(cameraButton)

        print(self.Post2.name)
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToViewController(_ unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        let sourceViewController = unwindSegue.source
        // Use data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue
    }

    func setupPreview() {
        // Configure previewLayer
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = camPreview.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        camPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    }

    //MARK:- Setup Camera

    func setupSession() -> Bool {

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

        // Setup Camera
        let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .front)!

        //AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)!

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
                activeInput = input
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device video input: \(error)")
            return false
        }

        // Setup Microphone
        let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio)!

        do {
            let micInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(micInput) {
                captureSession.addInput(micInput)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error setting device audio input: \(error)")
            return false
        }

        // Movie output
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(movieOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(movieOutput)
        }
        return true
    }

    func setupCaptureMode(_ mode: Int) {
        // Video Mode

    }

    //MARK:- Camera Session
    func startSession() {

        if !captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func stopSession() {
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            videoQueue().async {
                self.captureSession.stopRunning()
            }
        }
    }

    func videoQueue() -> DispatchQueue {
        return DispatchQueue.main
    }

    func currentVideoOrientation() -> AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
        var orientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
            default:
                 orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
         }

         return orientation
     }

    @objc func startCapture() {

        startRecording()

    }

    func tempURL() -> URL? {
        let directory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString

        if directory != "" {
            let path = directory.appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString + ".mp4")
            return URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        }

        return nil
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let vc = segue.destination as! VideoPlaybackViewController

        vc.videoURL = sender as? URL

    }

    func startRecording() {

        if movieOutput.isRecording == false {

            let connection = movieOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)

            if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
                connection?.videoOrientation = currentVideoOrientation()
            }

            if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
                connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
            }

            let device = activeInput.device

            if (device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported) {

                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    device.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                   print("Error setting configuration: \(error)")
                }

            }

            outputURL = tempURL()
            movieOutput.startRecording(to: outputURL, recordingDelegate: self)

            }
            else {
                stopRecording()
            }

       }

   func stopRecording() {

       if movieOutput.isRecording == true {
           movieOutput.stopRecording()
        }
   }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {

    }

    func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {

        if (error != nil) {

            print("Error recording movie: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            let videoRecorded = outputURL! as URL

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVideo", sender: videoRecorded)

        }

    }

}
```

***VideoPlaybackViewController***

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class VideoPlaybackViewController: UIViewController {

    @EnvironmentObject var post2: Post2

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer()
    let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!

    var videoURL: URL!


    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var postLabel: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.bounds
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoView.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL as URL)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

        avPlayer.play()

        print(self.post2.name)
        self.postLabel.text = self.post2.name
    }

    @IBAction func submitButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

[Screenshot of Storyboard with RecordVideoViewController and VideoPlaybackViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHS9x.png)